# Run a function every time an Angular controller is loaded

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, angularjs-rootscope

I want to run a function every time any Angular controller is loaded.

The best way I have found is to attach this handler in the first controller loaded on my site:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', 
  function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    myFunction();
  }
);
```

Is there a better alternative?

Comment: What is purpose of this function? Have you considered `run()` block? Many apps no way of knowing what first entry point will be

Comment: It's a call to Google Analytics just logging pageviews `ga('send', 'pageview');` - so ajax, and shouldn't be blocking the controller load

Comment: Controllers are not associated one-to-one with the concept of a "page" - they could, but don't always do. You may have multiple controllers, each nested within each other's scope, that deal with their own part of a view. So, from this perspective, calling `ga('sned', 'pageview')` would at best obscure your analytics. Logging  a state change, as you suggested in the question itself, is arguably the better approach than "run a function every time any Angular controller is loaded"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to execute a function every time the controller is loaded, the following would suffice.

```
var init=function(){
  //your code goes here
}
init();
```

But in most cases, you would require a function to be executed only on load of a specific page (route). In this case, use the following.

```
if ($location.url() == "/your/page/url")
{
  //Your function code or function call goes here 
}
```

**Edit:** For your specific need, the code for Google Analytics can be handled efficiently in Angular $http Interceptor. Refer [Angular $http Interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer moving that function into the resolve section of your `$stateProvider`. Your state config could look something like

```
.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {

  $stateProvider
  .state('myRoute', {
    url: '/myUrl',
    templateUrl: '/template.html',
    controller: 'MyController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    resolve: {
      dummyVariable: function(MyService, $stateParams) {

        MyService.functionToBeCalled();

        return true;
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Will using `resolve` block the controller loading until the AJAX request finishes?  I'm assuming it will just fire the ajax request and ajax will be async as usual - correct?